# How to set images and text on a specific position in a widget?

Tags: android, resize, widget, position

I am making a widget where i want to set texts and images at a specific position. I want an output like UCCW widgets. I have tried frame layout, relative layout, and canvas but nothing works like it. Whenever i resize the widget from 2x2 to some odd size like 4x2 then the positions of texts mess up. I want to know how to set them at specific positions and how do they automatically resize when the widget size is changed without any issue.

Image for reference:

[image: Image for reference]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `LinearLayout` with weights for the visible views and for the empty space.
Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <!--Placeholder (empty space) before.-->
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Hello" />

        <!--Placeholder (empty space) after. -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="7" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <!--Placeholder (empty space) before.-->
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="20" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="widget" />

        <!--Placeholder (empty space) after. -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="6" />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Widget 2x2:
[image: Widget screenshot 2x2]

Widget 4x2:
[image: Widget screenshot 4x2]

Comment: Thanks for your response, appreciate your effort. But the i want the elements to stay at their positions without changing their width and height. You can refer to UCCW, the app gives X,Y positions for texts, images, arcs,etc. I want the same effect. I have used canvas but i am unable to get the same effect for texts in it.